# How can I compile Midori with WebKit2?

Tags: midori, development

How can I compile Midori (with granite) to use WebKit2 instead of WebKit?

Answer (score 3):

Open up Terminal and do the following things:

1. Make sure you have the necessary dependencies to compile it. `apt-get build-dep` grabs almost everything from packaging, but you'll need to manually get WebKit2Gtk+

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep midori-granite
   sudo apt-get install libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev
   ```
2. Branch Midori's source code from Launchpad:

   ```
   bzr branch lp:midori
   ```
3. Change into the `midori` folder you just branched and make a build directory. Then change into that directory. You don't *need* to make a separate build directory, but I recommend it because it makes it easy to "clean" the branch in case something goes wrong in your build and you want to try again.

   ```
   cd midori
   mkdir build
   cd build
   ```
4. Configure CMake with the options necessary to build with Webkit2. If for whatever reason you're not interested in building with Granite, leave off the `-DUSE_GRANITE` part

   ```
   cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -DHALF_BRO_INCOM_WEBKIT2=true -DUSE_GRANITE=true ../
   ```
5. Make and test

   ```
   make
   ./midori/midori
   ```
6. If everything seems to be great and you want to install:

   ```
   sudo make install
   ```

Keep in mind that elementary carries some additional Midori patches in Packaging, so you may notice some small differences (read: breakages). You can [browse those patches here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~midori/midori/packaging-granite/files/head:/patches/). Also keep in mind that Midori isn't currently being built with WebKit2 because there are a number of unsolved bugs. You can [see known bugs here](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/midori/+spec/webkit2).

Answer (score -1):

The blog post [WebKitGTK+ 2.5.1: Good bye WebKit1](http://blogs.igalia.com/carlosgc/2014/08/01/webkitgtk-2-5-1-good-bye-webkit1/) suggests how to build WebKitGTK+ 2 (if it's not already installed / available):

```
cd webkitgtk
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX= -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=lib -DPORT=GTK -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .
make
checkinstall
```

Linux from Scratch [has instructions for building Midori](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/xfce/midori.html) with a switch for WebKitGTK+ 2 support. And Midori itself offers info on [how-to build with Granite support](http://midori-browser.org/contribute/) (`-DUSE_GRANITE=1`). So putting both together I come up with this:

```
cd midori
mkdir build &&
cd    build &&

cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr \
      -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release  \
      -DUSE_ZEITGEIST=OFF         \
      -DUSE_GTK3=1                \
      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_DOCDIR=/usr/share/doc/midori-0.5.11 \
      -DUSE_GRANITE=1             \
      ..  &&
make
checkinstall
```

You **could** try this and report back. What's the worst that could happen? (I'd suggest using a virtual machine, as I have no idea...)

Please note, I have used [`checkinstall`](https://wiki.debian.org/CheckInstall) instead of `make install` to (hopefully) make it easier to get rid of everything again.