# Geary blurred on HiDPI screen, possible to compile with latest WebKit version?

Tags: release-freya, pantheon-mail, hidpi

The mail content in Geary is displayed blurry on my HiDPI display, as are websites in Midori.

After some research I think using the latest WebKit version could fix that.

I found [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2486/how-can-i-compile-midori-with-webkit2/3009#3009) info about how to compile Midori with the latest WebKit version, but `libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev` does not seem to be in the repos and I am not certain about how to adapt the steps described therein for use with Geary.

Any help or info would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

No need to compile anything: you can just update to a newer `libwebkitgtk` - then Geary (and other applications like e.g. the WiFi login window) will use that instead of the old one. I think the issue was fixed in *2.4.9*, but the version currently available in the repository is *2.4.8*.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webkit-team/ppa
sudo sed -i s/trusty/vivid/g /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webkit-team-ppa-trusty.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-0
```

**Don't blame me if that breaks things - I destroyed a lot while finding the solution!**
*Edit:* fixed a lot of wrong things about this :D

Comment: So I have to make sure of this since I'm possibly about to break some things - the repo you're referring to contains a WebKit version > 2.4.8 then? Also, there are some broken dependencies, any insights as to how to resolve these? 
libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 : Depends on: libgstreamer1.0-0 (>= 1.4.0); however 1.2.4-0ubuntu1 is supposed to be installed
                      Depends on: libstdc++6 (>= 4.9); however 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is supposed to be installed 
(sorry for the rough translation)

Answer (score 1):

It's not currently possible to build Geary with WebKit2. You would have to branch the source code and manually port it (not a trivial task and not something it's possible to list steps for).